# Animation not looping in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

I can't figure out how to make this animation loop in Unity, the blue bar just stops. I'm probably missing something very obvious, I'm just learning how to animate. Thanks!

Picture of the problem --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5Yf.jpg

Comment: Are you sure about your animation frames ending, if there are more keyframes, it will try to finish them first and then start again? (Because you mentioned you already ticked loop)

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything with the keyframes is in order, I am using a sample from Mixamo and following this tutorial if maybe that gives some clarification. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vApG8aYD5aI&ab_channel=iHeartGameDev

Answer (score 3):

- Choose your animation and then press "Edit" on the top right.

[image]

- then click on loop options and press "Apply"

[image]

- this will make your animation always play

Answer (score 1):

Double-click the state to open the animation clip settings. You need to tick the Loop Pose setting to make it looping

Comment: I ticked both loop time and loop pose but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

select the animation in the folder and tick on the loop pose to make it loop, thanks

Comment: I ticked both loop time and loop pose but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: if it is humaniod or you are controlling the player, then untick the loop pose

Comment: I changed the rig animation to humanoid and it is now looping, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was constantly triggering the State to start in code. You should only trigger once, else the State will exit and start again, making it look like the looping is not working.